# Flask cannot redirect after receiving post request from Ajax in templates

Tags: python, flask, web, backend

I want to create a chatroom, in which, if people enter "!exit", then they will get out of the chatroom. The way I implement this idea is that whenever people send "!exit" message, Ajax will send a post request back to the view function. After receiving the request, the view function redirects the user to the homepage. However, right now, I think I can send a post request, since the console prints "success", but the code still does not redirect. This is my code:

In chat.html:

```
    <head> 
        <title> Chat room </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

                socket.on('message', function(msg) {
                    if (msg=="!exit") { 
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : "http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat",
                            data: {data: "Unmatched"},
                            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                            success: function() {
                                window.location.href = '/chat'
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else { 
                    $("#message-display").append('<div>'+ "person: " + msg+'</div>');
                    }
                });

                $('#sendbutt').on('click', function() {
                    socket.send($('#message-input').val());
                    $('#message-input').val('');
                });

                });
        </script>
        <div> Welcome to the chat room. You are chatting with a user. </div>
        <div> Type "!exit" if you want to stop chatting and return to the homepage. </div>
        <l id="message-display"> </l>
        <input type="text" id="message-input"> 
        <button id="sendbutt"> Send </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In main.py:

```
socketio=SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def homepage():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/chat', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def chat(): 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
    return render_template("chat.html")
@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(msg): 
    send(msg,broadcast=True)
```

Comment: Because AJAX calls don't do anything with 301 redirects from the server. They just treat it as "success". Change your success method in Javascript to redirect (it looks like it already redirects to /chat)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation! What if I want to send some data from the Ajax post request to the view that I'm redirecting to? Would I be able to do that if I redirect from the success method? As of right now, my only idea is to do that via the main.py's view function

Comment: You can either get rid of AJAX entirely by detecting the `!exit` text and then doing a form submit() on the page. Then your redirect would work.  Or get the data from your AJAX call in the javascript success method and pass it to the next page from there.